# Syntax error, insert "{" to complete EnumBody (at end of class)

Tags: java, syntax, enums

```
package checkers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


enum Job{SPAWN, KING, NORM};
enum myColor{RED, BLACK};

int tileRow;
int tileCol;
Job job;
myColor side;
JButton button;
Checker piece;
Color color;

public class Tile 
{
    public Tile(int posRow, int posCol, JPanel panel, ActionListener listener)
    {
        int tileRow = posRow;
        int tileCol = posCol;
        if(tileRow > 9 || tileRow < 1)
            job = Job.KING;
        else if(tileRow < 4 || tileRow > 6)
            job = Job.SPAWN;
        else
            job = Job.NORM;

        button = new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(83, 83));
        if(tileRow%2==0)
        {
            if(tileCol%2==0)
            {
                color = Color.BLACK;
            }
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        }
        else
        {
            if(tileCol%2!=0)
            {
                color = Color.BLACK;
            }
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        }
        button.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionListener) listener);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {

    }

    public boolean isClicked(Object source)
    {
        if(source == button)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }




}
```

**EDIT** I edited in the entirety of my code body. The myColor closing brace is, as far as Eclipse knows, 'supposed' to be after the classBody.

Eclipse wants me to remove myColor's closing brace, and replace it with a semi-colon; regardless of whether or not I place the semi-colon, Eclipse tells me that the closing brace is not supposed to be there, and if I remove it, reads my classBody closing brace as being the EnumBody closing brace.

I dunno what the hell is going on, but it's definitely causing weird things to happen within the class (making a Tile class+object for a game of checkers).

And by weird things, I mean I can't make an array of Tile objects from another class if I want Eclipse to read Tile as having no errors.

Comment: Add semicolons after `NORM` **and** `BLACK`. Works fine here after that.

Comment: Can you us the whole code? You might missing a }{ somewhere else.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos i can, yes

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i forgot to add semicolons when typing into stackoverflow. whoops. had them in there in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure the error message you are getting. Below example `EnumIssue.java` works fine:

```
public class EnumIssue {

    enum Job
    {
        SPAWN, KING, NORM
    }
    enum myColor
    {
        RED, BLACK
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job j = Job.SPAWN;
        myColor c = myColor.BLACK;
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SPAWN
BLACK
```

**Added after entire code was provided in question:**

Move the variable declarations in the class `Tile`. The updated snippet is below:

```
:
:
import javax.swing.JPanel;

enum Job{SPAWN, KING, NORM};
enum myColor{RED, BLACK};

//This is where current variable declarations are. Move them inside class.

public class Tile
{
    //This is where variable declarations are moved to. 
    int tileRow;
    int tileCol;
    Job job;
    myColor side;
    JButton button;
    Checker piece;
    Color color;

    public Tile(int posRow, int posCol, JPanel panel, ActionListener listener)
    {
        int tileRow = posRow;
        :
        :
```

Comment: I copy and pasted the entirety of my code into the OP. I spent another hour today mixing braces and semicolons around before I remembered I had posted here.

Nothing, as far as I can tell, is solving *all* my issues.

Comment: Updated answer after looking at the code posted in the question description.

Comment: ...that's honestly so incredibly embarassing. I'm not sure how I managed to miss that.